# R package assertive::assert_in not working

Tags: r, oop, testing

I am trying to use Richard Cotton's `assertive` R package to write a custom assertion to test whether an object belongs to a (custom S4) class. I am using the function `assert_engine` as in, for example `assert_engine(is.numeric, 1.5)`. I could equivalently write that same assertion as `assert_engine(class(1.5)== "numeric")` but I get different results:

```
> assert_engine(is.numeric, 1.5)
 
> assert_engine(class(1.5)=="numeric")

Error in predicate(...) : could not find function "predicate"
```

The expression `predicate(...)`does occur in the function `assert_engine`,

```
   assert_engine <- function (predicate, ..., msg = "The assertion failed.", what = c("all", 
        "any"), na_ignore = FALSE, severity = c("stop", "warning", 
        "message", "none")) 
{
    handler_type <- match.arg(severity)
    dots <- list(...)
    return_value <- if (length(dots) > 0) 
        dots[[1]]
    else NULL
    if (handler_type == "none") {
        return(invisible(return_value))
    }
    what <- match.fun(match.arg(what))
    predicate_name <- get_name_in_parent(predicate)
    ok <- predicate(...)
    if (inherits(ok, "scalar_with_cause")) {
        if (!isTRUE(ok)) {
            if (missing(msg)) {
                msg <- cause(ok)
            }
            give_feedback(handler_type, msg, predicate_name)
        }
    }
    else {
        really_ok <- if (na_ignore) {
            ok | is.na(ok)
        }
        else {
            ok & !is.na(ok)
        }
        if (!what(really_ok)) {
            msg <- paste(enc2utf8(msg), print_and_capture(ok), 
                sep = "\n")
            give_feedback(handler_type, msg, predicate_name)
        }
    }
    invisible(return_value)
}
```

which does look wrong, given that `predicate` is a variable not a function. Nevertheless the `assert_engine` function does work in the case `assert_engine(is.numeric, 1.5)`.

What is going wrong in my use to test `class`?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found that I can test the class of an object with `inherits`, as in

```
assert_engine(inherits( 1.5),"numeric"))
```

but I'd still like to know why I can't use `class`.